# How to create a mosaic from characters or small images?

Tags: generative-art, word-cloud

I want to create a piece of art similar to the following two images of Grace Hopper and Bill Gates:
I know how to create a word cloud and want to extend this knowledge to make something similar to this.
My input will involve an image and a series of characters or small images.
My output will be a composition of the images that looks like the input image
[image]
[image]

When I open [this link](https://blog.wolfram.com/2008/05/02/making-photo-mosaics/) the images are replaced with this: [image].

Comment: See https://blog.wolfram.com/2008/05/02/making-photo-mosaics/

Comment: the images won't load when I open the article

Comment: Go Wayback: https://web.archive.org/web/20090228132706/https://blog.wolfram.com/2008/05/02/making-photo-mosaics/

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/908790) and [this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2153018).